# How to design data structure for a specific table header

Tags: javascript, css, data-structures

All:

I am not good at Data structure, currently what I want to build is a table with two-row header(just like excel, you use the first two row as header, the first row may have several column merged together, and under it(in the second row), there are several columns ), and the crucial feature is it allows user to adjust column width by dragging column(in the second row) right side border.

Current the main difficulty for me is: how to design a data structure to make according column respond to the dragging action, for example:

[image]

the columns with black text can be dragged by right side border, and when resize, it only affect the left border position of the column next to it on the right side. The grey column will change accordingly(I am thinking it like event handler, once you drag something under it, it will get updated too) if the total width of the columns under it changed.

Thanks

Comment: You said "I want to build," but it sounds like you want us to build.

Comment: @WesFoster "If I have seen further than others, it is by standing upon the shoulders of giants." -- Isaac Newton.  I Just want certain detial about how to implement in terms of data structure or algorithm but not the code

Comment: "if your question generally covers a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" -- StackOverflow Help Docs

Comment: Your question is very broad. A single answer wouldn't necessarily be the right answer. Try doing what needs done, then come here when you have a more specific question to ask :)